# UpgradeSchema for category attribute M2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, category-attribute

I have created custom category attribute by below setup.

```
namespace Hello\Catattribute\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;


    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){
            $eavSetup -> removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'right_top');
            $eavSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category :: ENTITY, 'right_top', [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => 'Top Right Html',
                        'input' => 'textarea',
                        'required' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 110,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                        'group' => 'General Information'
                    ]
            );
        }

    }
}
```

Now I want to add some more custom attributes for category but without creating a new module, to do so I have created an UpgradeSchema and changed the setup version in module.xml.

```
namespace Hello\Catattribute\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface {

    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $eavSetup = $setup->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            $eavSetup -> removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'background_img');
            $eavSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category :: ENTITY, 'background_img', [
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'label' => 'Background Image',
                        'input' => 'image',
                        'backend' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image::class,
                        'required' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 115,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'group' => 'General Information',
                    ]
            );



        }
        $eavSetup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

But it's not working. Please help me or suggest me that how can I upgrade EAV setup schema.

Answer (score 6):

Try below code. You should created **UpgradeData.php** instead of creating **UpgradeSchema.php**.

```
<?php

namespace Hello\Catattribute\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;

class UpgradeData
    implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Category setup factory
     *
     * @var CategorySetupFactory
     */
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.2', '<')) {
            $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            'catalog_category',
            'page_not_found',
            array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Display on 404 Page',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'sort_order' => 3,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ));
        }
    }   
}
```

Please check the version of your module and change accordingly in **UpgradeData.php** and **module.xml** file

Don't forget to run `setup:upgrade` command